# Загрузка файлов с телефона на сервер с помощью PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте! Делаю одну программу и в ней нужно послать перечень файлов с телефона на сервер, без понятия как это сделать, знаю только как [заливать файлы на сервер из этого туториала](http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/25/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap/), данные по которым нужно посылать перечень файлов выглядят так:

```
{
    "url": "https://91.228.199.95/ksiywFac63f2hs/",
    "output": "/home/user/gleb/",
    "user": "testuser1",
    "pass": "67890",
    "items": [{
        "distname": "userfotos.php",
        "locname": "moifotos"}]}]
```

Нужно постом послать перечень файлов с устройства [вот сюда](https://91.228.199.95/ksiywFac63f2hs/userfotos.php), как мне получить этот перечень на javascript ?

Comment: Может кто-то точней подсказать? Не получается увидеть файлы из директории.
 options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/mnt/sdcard/Img')+1); не выводит ни одного файла.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

phonegap - это обертка, позволяющая код html/css/javascript перевести в формат, исполняемый на мобильных устройствах как приложение.
этот самый фонегап прекрасно понимает жквери, поэтому для отправки запроса из приложения, достаточно написать стандартный для js/jQ код, использующий (к примеру) методы

```
$.get(  "myscript.php",  {},  onSuccess );
```

или аналогично post с последующей обработкой обычными методами жабаскрипт.
не пишу как получить данные с телефона, поскольку это описано в мануалке по фонегап, суть надеюсь понятна.

работает 100%, я уже такое выполнял.

Comment: А можно ссылку где это описано, тут http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer, написано как закидывать сразу файлы, про перечень ни слова.

Comment: какого объема файлы?.. 
в принципе, для перечня можно их брать по одному с телефона через FileReader и так же отправлять уже методом жКвери (однозначно пост, или даже .ajax), а на сервере написать пхп-скрипт, который получает файл и далее его реализует куда-то..

Comment: файлы разные, картинки по 10 кб, архивы по 100 мб, и так далее. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: да, и я посмотрел ссылку на пример - там вообще все просто, должно и без жквери работать, единственное - это обеспечить на сервере фтп-пользователя с нужным именем и паролем, убедится, что папка, куда будет идти закачка открыта для этого ну и убедиться, что провайдер хостинга вообще разрешает своим юзерам такое самоуправство с файлами :)

Comment: и все же мне сперва нужен перечень файлов, а потом уже сами файлы лить)

Comment: тут надо понимать, как перечень файлов формируется, если они в какой-то папке болтаются, то должно помочь "DirectoryReader - An object that lists files and directories in a directory.", если их пользователь предварительно выбирает где-то, то полный путь забивать в массив, затем по одному заливать аплоадом через цикл.

Comment: У меня проблема не как послать перечень, а как получить его, как мне сделать что бы пользователь с телефона мог выбрать файлы на посылку? Как мне это реализовать на js ?